# Multi-user env, SSH ZSH - command not found: shopt

Tags: bash, ssh, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I just installed ZSH on a remote server where we are 2 "admins".
I switched my default shell to ZSH with `chsh -s $(which zsh)`. `echo $SHELL` gives the output `/usr/bin/zsh` which proves it.
But, when I open my ssh session I receive an error like:

```bsh
/etc/profile.d/vk.sh:30: command not found: shopt
```

This error appears only at startup and I see it only once when opening an ssh session.

In my understanding, the other admin placed some custom script with his own aliases and using `shopt -s histappend` command there as well.

My question is, why my SSH ZSH session invoking that script at startup?
Shouldn't it be scoped just to my profile?

What would be a graceful solution for me to run ZSH without affecting/touching his stuff? Should I ask him to move that thing somewhere else in his home dir?

Comment: Hmm... AFAIK `/etc/profile` (and scripts it sources in `/etc/profile.d`) really ought to be POSIX/Bourne compatible, for exactly this reason. OTOH I thought zsh should use its own `/etc/zsh/zprofile` over `/etc/profile` anyhow? One old-school workaround you could consider is changing your actual login shell to bash and then `exec /usr/bin/zsh` at the end of your own `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile`, if you have one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/etc/profile` file contains system wide profile settings. Within that file, many distributions are sourcing scripts within `/etc/profile.d`. Hence, all interactive logins will invoke what is in that folder.  If you want a profile script to be scoped to one account, you have to either

1. move that script into `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` (for bash users), or
2. add login in the `vk.sh` to skip execution based on the logged in user.

Comment: Yes, i think the correct way is to ask him to move his scripts somewhere upstream. ~/.profile IMHO is a good place to put that.

Comment: Just remember that ~/.profile is not sourced by bash if ~/.bash_profile exists. It's a peculiarity of bash where it has a built-in preference for its own (i.e. .bash_profile)  over posix (.profile) for its environment setup files.